# How to select data from two tables in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I trying to write Ecto query which will be select data from two tables at the same time. Like `Select t1.*,t2.* from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.id=1 and t2.id=2` I can't find solution, found only way to write raw SQL and it's looks like not good.

Like variant -using preload, but it's spawn additional query.

```
comments_query = from c in Comment, order_by: c.published_at
Repo.all from p in Post, preload: [comments: ^comments_query]
```

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Try this from Ecto.Query

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5

```
from t1 in Table1,
   join: t2 in Table2, on: t1.t2_id == t2.id,
   select: {t1.title, t2.text}
```