# Select data from two tables but return dynamically selected fields inside map

Tags: sql, select, join, elixir, ecto

I have a query which successfully joins table with correct condition but its not returning the joinee table selected data in a map. Is there a way I can get data inside map like

```
from t1 in "Table1",
   join: t2 in "Table2", on: t1.t2_id == t2.id,
   select: map(t1, [:id, {"Table2", [:id]}])
```

Should return something like `[%{"id": 1, "Table2": %{"id": 1}}]` when above query runs but it only returns `[%{"id": 1}]`

Note: Kinda similar question
[How to select data from two tables in Ecto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240347/how-to-select-data-from-two-tables-in-ecto) but its not returning in map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it

```
from t1 in "Table1",
 join: t2 in "Table2", on: t1.t2_id == t2.id,
 select: map(t1, [:id]),
 select_merge: %{Table2: map(t2, [:id])}
```

[Credit goes to](https://elixirforum.com/t/select-data-from-two-tables-but-return-selected-fields-dynamically-inside-map/13034/2?u=tanweerdev) elixirform user